# i want to post the json data and get the response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, rest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


<script>
var SendInfo= { SendInfo: [{"dataKey":"1013"}]};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/getData',
            data: JSON.stringify(SendInfo),
            contentType: "application/json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i am parsing the json data but  i am getting the 500 server error but everything seems to work fine in postman plese suggest any changes [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the request you are sending and compared the ajax request to the postman request on the server side?

You seem to be sending two different JSONs, in your ajax code you have `{ SendInfo: [{"dataKey":"1013"}]}` and in your postman request you have just `{"dataKey":"1013"}`. These are different objects and your back end might not understand them both.

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to send this in your post request.

```
var SendInfo= {"dataKey":"1013"};
```